# jQuery UI Dialog removes html

Tags: html, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a web page in which an icon (font awesome book) when clicked should  display a text passage. The trouble is it doesn't. If "span.fa-book" is used as the selector in the jQuery assigned to the variable "ws_story_dialog", the effect is to remove the book icon from the page. Similarly, "div.ws_btn_group" removes the grouped book and right arrow icons, "div#ws_title" the page title and "div#word_set" the entire page. Also, removing the book icon from the "ws_btn_group", and placing it elsewhere eg. next to the "word_set" tag, has no effect. However, if the selector is empty ""  then clicking on the book icon displays the help alert but no dialog, which suggests that the problem is in the dialog config code. Finally, if the "span#ws_title_text" selector is used, the book icon is partly hidden but when clicked the dialog displays OK. Checking with Firebug shows that the html around Word Set is being removed.
 Html:

```
<div id="word_set">
  <div id="ws_title"><span id="ws_title_text">Word Set 1</span>
        <div class="ws_btn_group">
         <a class="btn"><span class="fa fa-book fa_book_ws"></span></a>         
          <a class="btn" href="/index.php/courses/word-set-tests/word-set-tests-1-10/word-set-test"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa_arrow_circle_right_ws"></span></a> 
       </div> 
    </div>
  <div id="ws_dialog"><div id="wsd_text"></div></div> 
   <div id="ws_centering">   
    <div id="left_col"> 
      <p class="word_set">1<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e01">the</span><span class="color_up audio" id="b1t01">คำนำหน้านามเจาะจง </span>
    ...
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var ws_story_dlog =  jQuery("").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,
      dialogClass: "",
      show: "slide",
      height: 400,
     width: 600,
    create: function() {
            jQuery(this).parents(".ui-dialog")
            .css("border", "0.1em solid #000093")
            .css("background", "#ECE6FF")
            .css("border-radius", "3%")
            .find(".ui-dialog-content")
            .css("font-family", "verdana")
            .css("font-size", "1em")
            .css("font-style", "normal")
            .css("color", "#1901B2")
            .css("padding-top", "15px")
            .find(".ui-dialog-header")
            .css("display","none");
        }
    });    
  jQuery("div#word_set").on("click", "span.fa-book", function(evnt) {   //"span.fa-book"
     alert("hello");
    ws_story_dlog.dialog("open");
    evnt.stopPropagation();
    jQuery("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").hide(); 
    jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header'); 
    var ws_story_html = '<div class="ws_story"><p id="story_title_ws1" class="ws_story_title">This is a story using some of the words from Word Set 1</p><p>Please read and listen carefully</p><p>thai</p><p  id="story_ws1"  class="ws_story">Sed ut perspiciatis...</p><span class="fa fa-volume-up fa_volume_ws"></span></div>';
    ws_story_dlog.html(ws_story_html);
  });
});
```

Googling hasn't shown up any info but this - [jQuery ui dialog removes div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923045/jquery-ui-dialog-removes-div) -
seems to refer to a similar problem. So what's going on here? Why is jquery dialog removing html? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've seen JQuery do this before when my document had missing closing tags - when it makes the dialog i think it consumes the content of the selector and puts it in a floating div. If your tags are not opened and closed properly, it gets confused and eats more than it should.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've checked the document at http://validator.w3.org/. it had a few errors but correcting these had no effect. Any suggestions from anyone would be most welcome. I'm short of ideas on a solution. I hadn't mentioned that the web site is joomla based but I don't think that's an issue.